# MySQL get team chats sorted by last message send time

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I have 2 tables, responsible for teams and for team messages. Lets say their structure is like this:

```
teams
team_id |   team_name
--------+------------
      1 |  First team
      2 | Second team
      3 |  Third team

team_messages
team_message_id | team_id | message_text | send_time
----------------+---------+--------------+----------
              1 |       1 |              |         1
              2 |       3 |              |         2
              3 |       2 |              |         3
```

The way i want to show teams is:

```
team_id | team_name
--------+------------
      2 | Second Team
      3 | Third team
      1 | First team
```

So basically i need to show all teams ordered by last message in that team desc. What i have tried is

```
SELECT * FROM teams a
ORDER BY
(
    SELECT `send_time`
    FROM team_messages b
    ORDER BY b.`t_message_id` DESC
    LIMIT 1
) DESC
```

But this seems to give wrong result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your original query selects just one row, the latest message time, for all records. Try something like

```
SELECT a.*, (
    SELECT max(send_time)
    FROM team_messages b
    WHERE b.team_id = a.team_id
    ) as ord
FROM teams a
ORDER BY ord DESC
```

You might need to move it into derived table if MySQL doesn't allow alias in order by:

```
SELECT * FROM (
   SELECT a.*, (
     SELECT max(send_time)
     FROM team_messages b
     WHERE b.team_id = a.team_id
     ) as ord
   FROM teams a
)
ORDER BY ord DESC
```

Comment: Nice! Both queries work fine on my server, and perfomance seems to be equal. By the way you forgot allias to the first `select` statement. But anyway thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
select * from teams a join team_messages b on a.team_id = b.team_id
order by b.send_time desc
```

Comment: Nice suggestion, i added group by `b.team_id` to show team only one time, however this query gets the very first message in team instead of last